# How to show fragment only when button pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to show an image below a button only after the button has been pressed. My problem is that the fragment is shown immediately when the app is started and not only after the button has been pressed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void say_hello(View view){
        Fragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_articles, container, false);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

        android:text="PRESS THIS"
        android:id = "@+id/test_button"
        android:background="@drawable/test_button"
        android:onClick="say_hello"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.tic_tac_toe.ExampleFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="643dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/cool_dog">
</ImageView>
```

I'm guessing the fragment shows up when the app is started because of the name I give to the fragment in the XML, but the fragment needs a name otherwise I only get error. How do I get the fragment to display nothing before I have clicked the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<fragment />` view in your xml, you can use `Framelayou`t and add your fragment to this Framelayout on button click using the following code -

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.mainframe, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Where `mainframe` is the id of Framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG");
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment);
```

inside your click event.

Comment: The problem is that the image is displayed before it gets to the click event.